# Compiler can't find frameworks anymore after moving to objective-c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I am extending a current c++ project with objective c code. For this purpose I compile the code as objective-c++ code. But since i changed the ending of a .cpp file into .mm, the compiler can't find two includes anymore. 
One is a framework (#include <QTime>) and the other a simple header (#include "timecoder.h"). I changed the path of timecoder.h to its relative path and the compiler didn't complain anymore. But the problem with QTime still persists.

Do you have any idea what i could do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using #import instead of #include.